# Insertar dato de un Array a otro Array

Tags: java

```
Arrayuno = {"Bélgica", "México", "Nicaragua", "Alemania " }
```

// este es el primer Array ya con datos

```
String ArrayDos = new String[2];
Int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < Array uno.length;i++) {
  if ( i == 1) {
         ArrayDos [0] = [i];
  } 
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no logro que el segundo vector se llene con los datos  en la posición del primero Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante fácil, primero debes de crear el segundo arreglo con el mismo tamaño que el primero, y ya con esto sólo debes iterar(de la forma que ya lo hiciste) y copiar el elemento `i` del arreglo1 a la posición `i` del arreglo2:

```
    String arreglo1[] = {"Bélgica", "México", "Nicaragua", "Alemania "};
    String arreglo2[] = new String[arreglo1.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arreglo1.length; i++){
        arreglo2[i] = arreglo1[i];
    }
```

Ahora arreglo2 contiene todo lo del arreglo1. Ahora, si quieres mover sólo un determinado número de elementos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
String arreglo2[] = new String[n]; //n = número de elementos que quieras copiar
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arreglo2[i] = arreglo1[i];
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: hola, lo que realmente quiero es que el arreglo  dos solo guarde dos valores del primer arreglo.. Es decir que del arreglo dos guarde a bélgica y a mexico. Esto con el fin de hacer otro proceso mas adelante.

Comment: Sólo debes de seguir la misma lógica iterando para el número de elementos que requieras, siguiendo el ejemplo n sería igual a 2, en tu caso.